# How to add thumb versions of images I have already uploaded with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, minimagick

I'm creating thumb versions of new images being uploaded and keeping the original file as well. But I've only just added this into my app and there are like 600 images already uploaded over time that don't have thumb versions. I want the images already uploaded to have thumbs as well.

I can see from reading the carrierwave docs [that you can run a script to re upload images in the DB to be a different size](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#recreating-versions). But this replaces the original image with the newly sized image.

Is there a way for me to do something similar to what they have there in the docs but save it to the `image_thumb` column and not replace the image in the `original_image` column? Basically run through the `original_image` column, resizing them and saving it to the `image_thumb` column.

Comment: Usually carrierwave does keep your full sized version. So by running `recreate_versions` you should end up with your original size + your resized image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carrierwaves `recreate_versions!` only affects the processed versions of the uploaded files and the original file is kept as-is. That means it should be safe for you to call `recreate_versions!`. You can see proof for that behaviour in this [pull request](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/2020).

Comment: Ok thanks. So to clarify it does leave the original files and the `original_file` column alone and make the thumbs and save the location of the thumbs in the `image_thumb` column. Sorry I just want to double check before I run it and have all the `original_file` db records renamed to the thumb file name.

Comment: It doesn't do anything with your DB. In your DB, there's only the original filename, e.g. `myimage.jpg`. If you recreate the versions, the DB stays the same, but you get additional getters that return the url to the thumb. You would then get the original file using `my_model_instance.original_file.url` and your resized version using `my_model_instance.original_file.image_thumb.url`(given your uploader is mounted on the `original_file` field and your thumb version is called `image_thumb`; see the second code sample in the [doc](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#adding-versions)